# Heroku only initializes some of my models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, heroku

So I ran

```
 heroku db:push
```

And it returned

```
 Sending schema
 Schema:        100% |==========================================| Time: 00:00:08
 Sending indexes
 schema_migrat: 100% |==========================================| Time: 00:00:00
 projects:   100% |==========================================| Time: 00:00:00
 tasks:         100% |==========================================| Time: 00:00:00
 users:         100% |==========================================| Time: 00:00:00
 Sending data
 8 tables, 70,551 records
 groups:        100% |==========================================| Time: 00:00:00
 schema_migrat: 100% |==========================================| Time: 00:00:00
 projects:   100% |==========================================| Time: 00:00:00
 tasks:         100% |==========================================| Time: 00:00:02
 authenticatio: 100% |==========================================| Time: 00:00:00
 articles:       100% |==========================================| Time: 00:08:27
 users:         100% |==========================================| Time: 00:00:00
 topics:        100% |==========================================| Time: 00:01:22
 Resetting sequences
```

And when I went to

```
  heroku console
```

This worked

```
  >> Task
  => Task(id: integer, topic: string, content: string,
```

This worked

```
 >> User
  => User(id: integer, name: string, email: string,
```

But the rest only returned something like

```
 >> Project
   NameError: uninitialized constant Project
/home/heroku_rack/lib/console.rb:150
/home/heroku_rack/lib/console.rb:150:in `call'
/home/heroku_rack/lib/console.rb:28:in `call'


>> Authentication
  NameError: uninitialized constant Authentication
/home/heroku_rack/lib/console.rb:150
/home/heroku_rack/lib/console.rb:150:in `call'
```

**update 1:**

And when I typed

```
  >> ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables
```

it returned

```
   => ["projects", "groups", "tasks", "topics", "articles", "schema_migrations", "authentications", "users"]
```

Using heroku's SQL console plugin

I got

```
 SQL> show tables
 +-------------------+
 |    table_name     |
 +-------------------+
 | authentications   |
 | topics            |
 | groups            |
 | projects          |
 | schema_migrations |
 | tasks             |
 | articles          |
 | users             |
 +-------------------+
```

So I think they are existing in heroku's database already.

There is probably something wrong with rack db:migrate

**update 2:**

I ran rack db:migrate locally in both production and development modes and nothing wrong happened.

But when I ran it on heroku 
it only returned:

```
  $ heroku rake db:migrate
 (in /disk1/home/slugs/389817_1c16250_4bf2-f9c9517b-bdbd-49d9-8e5a-a87111d3558e/mnt)
  $
```

Also, I am using sqlite3

**update 3:**

so I opened up heroku console and typed in the following command

```
class Authentication < ActiveRecord::Base;end
```

Amazingly I was able to call Authentication class, but once I exited, nothing was changed.

Comment: Did you run your migrations on heroku?

Comment: I believe I ran my migrations

Comment: I believe I ran "heroku rake db:migrate", except it didn't show anything besides my dyno address.

Comment: How about 'heroku rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error:

```
 >> Project  
   NameError: uninitialized constant Project
```

means that Project model is missing, this is not belongs to the database.

try:

```
git add .  
git commit -am 'update'
git push heroku master
```

Answer (score 2):

you called it `pojects` it appears and `authenticato`

Also, you've heroku restarted the app right?

Oh, and you have commited the files in git and did a normal `git push heroku master` i hope as well?

you just keep talking about heroku db:push which i hardly ever use that command in day to day commits.

Comment: How about schema_migrat? I think heroku just truncates the string. And it shows poject because I deleted "r" accidentally when I was trying to paste the message.

Comment: Weird. Do they show up here (in dev and in heroku?) when you use this in console: Class.constants (towards the bottom usually) Then to see the single constant:  Class.constants.grep /Project/

Comment: I used Class.constants.grep /User/
it returned => ["User"]
However, when I used Class.constants.grep /Project/ or Class.constants.grep /Projects/ it returned => []

Comment: And ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables shows projects is actually a table in Heroku's database

Comment: Ok dude, you need to grab the heroku database gem... it's like a console for the database and you have to see if you can access Project that way.  look on github, as i'm having dinner now.

Comment: I accessed projects table on heroku, and I can also see all the records...I am really confused right now.

Answer (score 1):

If you were actually missing the Tables in SQLite you would see an error like `Project(Table doesn't exist)`

Comment: I typed in "Nonsense" and it returned the same error message.

Comment: Right, as you should. In other words, the error message is Rails saying that it has no idea what that class is. If Rails actually knew what it is... and in addition you were missing a table it should return that `(Table doesn't exist)` error.

Comment: What I'm trying to infer, is that the problem is not with the table existing, not existing, or lacking records. The problem is that the class is not being recognized at all. 

It seems like the problem is in your Model files. Either they are incorrect, or you didn't add them to your commits or they're being ignored. If that's still not the case. Try to debug it by creating the class in the console manually.

Comment: But they worked well on local server? Anyway I will try to create them in the console.

Comment: It is weird, ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables returns result that includes "projects", however when I tried Project<ActiveRecord::Base it said it's not initialized.

Comment: So I ran class Authentication < ActiveRecord::Base;end in my heroku console, now I can access my table. But I don't understand, why aren't all these files under model folder working?

Comment: Pull down your app from Heroku to a different directory and see what's different between your local copy and the one you pulled down.

`git clone git@heroku.com:yourapp.git` Also make sure you're not on a different branch and what not.